# changing form action with play 2.0

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to render a form with action POST using play 2.10

```
@form(action = routes.Application.sentiment, args = 'id -> "helloform", 'method -> "POST")
```

The output for this is (I verified this in play console)

```
<form action="/sentiment" method="GET" id="helloform" method="POST">
```

The net effect of this in a browser is it ends up ignoring the second method attribute. What am I doing wrong? How do I override the default form method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@form` helper determines form's `method` argument on the action's `route`, so to change it you should change route

```
/GET    /sentiment  controllers.Application.sentiment
```

to

```
/POST   /sentiment  controllers.Application.sentiment
```

(or vice versa) and do not declare the method in the view.

```
@form(action = routes.Application.sentiment, args = 'id -> "helloform")
```

Comment: Now, that makes sense. Stupid of me, I assumed html generation is independent of handlers.